# Replace a string that matches a pattern using preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I want to replace the occurrences of the pattern "binary_function([x,y])" with substring "XY" in a given string.

I have it working with the following code:

```
// $string is the string to be searched
$string = preg_replace_callback('/binary_function\(\[(\S),(\S)\]\)/', function ($word) {
        $result = strtoupper($word[1]) . strtoupper($word[2]);              
        return $result;
        }, $string);
```

However, I also want it to replace "binary_function([x1,y1])" with substring "X1Y1", and any length of the arguments inside the square brackets e.g. [x11,y12], [var1,var2], etc.

I tried this:

```
// $string is the string to be searched
$string = preg_replace_callback('/binary_function\(\[(\S+),(\S+)\]\)/', function ($word) {
        $result = strtoupper($word[1]) . strtoupper($word[2]);              
        return $result;
        }, $string);
```

but it did not work.

Can anyone please help here?

Thanks.

Comment: `'/binary_function\(\[([^][\s,]+),([^][\s,]+)]\)/'`

Comment: Awesome :-) Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
'/binary_function\(\[([^][\s,]+),([^][\s,]+)]\)/'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sRTjYF/1)

**Regex details**

- `binary_function\(\[` - a `binary_function([` text
- `([^][\s,]+)` - Group 1: any one or more (due to `+`) chars other than `]`, `[`, whitespace and `,`
- `,` -  a comma
- `([^][\s,]+)` - Group 2: any one or more (due to `+`) chars other than `]`, `[`, whitespace and `,`
- `]\)` - a `])` string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.