# Using preg_replace_callback to find and replace a function signature with a variable number of parameters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

Using the PHP [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function, I want to replace the occurrences of the pattern "function([x1,x2])" with substring "X1X2", "function([x1,x2,x3])" with substring "X1X2X3", and in general: "function([x1,x2,...,x2])" with substring "X1X2...Xn" -- in a given string.

Thanks to [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64314312/replace-a-string-that-matches-a-pattern-using-preg-replace-callback), I have it working for functions that take two arguments:

```
// $string is the string to be searched
$string = preg_replace_callback('/function\(\[([^][\s,]+),([^][\s,]+)\]\)/', function ($word) {
        $result = strtoupper($word[2]) . strtoupper($word[2]);              
        return $result;
        }, $string);
```

I want to move one step further and make it work for functions with an arbitrary number of arguments. I tried using the regex `'/function\(\[[([^][\s,]+)]+[,]*\]\)/'` as a way of saying I want a repeated non-white substring followed optionally by a comma -- to account for the last function argument that is not followed by a comma. This however made PHP moan about the regex not being correct.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match and capture all contents between `function([` and `])` with a simple `binary_function\(\[(.*?)]\)` regex and then split the contents with a comma, and join back the uppercased strings:

```php
$text = 'binary_function([x,y]) and binary_function([x1,y1,z1])';
echo preg_replace_callback('~binary_function\(\[(.*?)]\)~', function ($m) {
    return implode("", array_map(function ($x) { return strtoupper($x); }, explode(",", $m[1])));
}, $text);
// => XY and X1Y1Z1
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/4ECni).

You may `trim()` the input values if there can be spaces inside the `([` and `])`.